# How to ask choices from user in multi line?

Tags: botframework

I'm asking user to select from multiple options as follows

```
var reportData = {
    "Report A Traffic Violation": {
        intent: 'report_a_traffic_violation'
    },
    "Report a Lost Property": {
        intent: 'report_a_traffic_violation'
    },
    "Describe Incident": {
        intent: '/describeIncident'
    }
};

builder.Prompts.choice(session, "please select from options", reportData);
```

But the options shows to the user in single line. How can I show the options to the user using multiple lines as follows?

1. option one
2. option two
3. option three

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Node.js

Based on the code you provided I suppose you are using node.js

You may have a look to the Contoso-Flowers sample provided by Microsoft, in its `settings` function: [code](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/demo-ContosoFlowers/bot/dialogs/settings.js) here and preview with the list visible [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/demo-ContosoFlowers).

Here is how they are handling the list:

```
var SettingChoice = {
    Email: 'edit_email',
    Phone: 'edit_phone',
    Addresses: 'edit_addresses',
    Cancel: 'cancel'
};

var lib = new builder.Library('settings');
lib.dialog('/', [
    // Display options
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, 'settings_intro', [
            session.gettext(SettingChoice.Email),
            session.gettext(SettingChoice.Phone),
            session.gettext(SettingChoice.Addresses),
            session.gettext(SettingChoice.Cancel)
        ]);
    },
```

Did you try to use an array like here?

### C#

For those building their bots in C#, you just have to specify your  `PromptStyle` to `PromptStyle.PerLine`

Answer (score 0):

For js : Although '\n' is the universal newline characters.
For c# SDK : Environment.NewLine.

Comment: For C# you have PromptStyle.PerLine setting that is doing it automatically for you

Comment: how can I add new line character to `reportData` object?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the listStyle parameter:

```
builder.Prompts.choice(
    session,
    "please select from options", 
    reportData,
    {listStyle: builder.ListStyle.list}
);
```

More information on list styles in Bot Framework documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt